# Elementary question regarding a proof in predicate logic

Tags: proof-verification, logic, proof-explanation, predicate-logic

I have been trying to apply the proof-diagram scheme of 'transition to pure mathemtaics text books' to the folowing problem in elementary logic and would greatly appreciate some help and corrections to the approach.

> Consider the $L_2-structure$ $A$ with
>
> - Domain of discourse the set of all European cities.
> - $|Q^1|_A=\{Florence,Stockholm,Barcelona \}$
> - $|R^2|_A=\{<d,e> : \text{d is smaller than e}\}$
> - $|a|_A=Florence$
> - $|b|_A=London$
>
> Prove : $|\forall x (Q^1x \rightarrow R^2xb)|_A=T$

**Informal Attempt:**

Using the definitions of satisfaction:

$|\forall x (Q^1x \rightarrow R^2xb)|_A=T$
$\quad$ iff $|\forall x (Q^1x \rightarrow R^2xb)|_A ^\alpha=T$ for any variable assignmnet (abbreviated : VA) $\alpha$
$\quad$ iff $|(Q^1x \rightarrow R^2xb)|_A^\beta=T$ for any VAs $\alpha$ and $\beta$ whereby $\beta$ differs from $\alpha$  in x at most.
$\quad$ iff $ |Q^1x|_A ^\beta=F$ or $|R^2xb|_A^\beta=T$ for any VAs $\alpha$ and $\beta$ whereby $\beta$ differs from $\alpha$  in x at most.

Therefore I thought the proof-diagram is as follows

**Let $\alpha$ be an arbitrary VA.

$\quad$ Let $\beta$ be the VA found differing from $\alpha$ in x at most.

$\quad \quad$ Prove $ |Q^1x|_A ^\beta=F$ or $|R^2xb|_A^\beta=T$**

Note:

(i) $ |Q^1x|_A ^\beta=F$ iff $ |x|_A ^\beta \notin |Q^1x|_A$

$\quad$Since $\beta$ can be chosen then we can define the assignment such   that $ |x|_A ^\beta \notin |Q^1x|_A$.

(ii) $|R^2xb|_A^\beta=T$ iff $<|x|_A^\beta,|b|_A> \in |R^2|_A$

$\quad$ Defining $|x|_A ^\beta \in |Q^1x|_A$ yields $<|x|_A^\beta,|b|_A> \in |R^2|_A$ since $|b|_A=London$
$\quad$ and all European cities in $|Q^1x|_A$ are smaller than London.

(iii) Since $\beta$ differs from $\alpha$ at most in x,does this mean that **either** $\beta$ assigns the same element to x as $\alpha$ **or** $\beta$ assigns a different element to x as $\alpha$ ?

I do not really now how to continue to yield the textbook answer given below. Are these steps/reasonings correct in the first place?

The textbook omits all these steps and simply states :

> Let $\alpha$ be an arbitrary variable assignment .There are two
>   cases.First Case : $|x|_A^\alpha$ in $|Q^1|_A$..... Second Case :
>   $|x|_A^\alpha$ not in $|Q^1|_A$.....

There is no mention of $\beta$ anywhere or how/why these two cases are obtained.

Sorry if this is a silly question!
Any clarifications would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: Very similar to yesterday's post... The symbolism is very complicated and the problem is very simple. Do you really need a "ultra formal" proof ? The problem amounts to : "is it true that Florence, Stockholm and Barcelona are smaller than London ?" (regarding population, I think...)

Comment: Thank you for your response.The symbolism is taken from the book and so is not more or less complicated than its source :-) .

Comment: Regarding you attempt, the start is Ok. You arrive at two cases : (i) $|Q^1 x|^{\beta}_A  = \text F$ that means exactly that $\beta$ maps $x$ "outside" of $|Q^1|_A$. In the second case (ii) we have $\beta (x) \in  |Q^1|_A$, in which case $|Q^1 x|^{\beta}_A  = \text T$ and also $|R^2 xb|^{\beta}_A = \text T$.

Comment: I think this is one of those cases where I applied the definitions of satisfaction verbatim without realising that alpha is actually 'pointless' in the universally quantifies statement since there are no free variables in it anyways...Therefore beta should be alpha in my  attempt....in which case the case distinctions seem to 'drop out'?

Comment: Yes; you have to prove that $\forall x \varphi$ holds. According to the approach I know (Enderton), this means to prove that $|\varphi^{[\alpha(x|d)]}|_A$ holds for every $d \in A$, where $\alpha(x|d)$ is the same as $\alpha$ except for assigning object $d$ to var $x$.

Comment: Thank you.So,the final proof diagram should really be : Let $\alpha$ be a VA over A.Prove $|Q^1x|_A^\alpha=F$ or $|R^2xb|_A^\alpha=T$ ?...and from there 'reverse-engineer' the case distinctions?

Comment: Yikes! Is this supposed to be an exercise for students just learning the basic methods of proof??? I'm guessing it would do more harm than good. I would start with something simple like proving $A \land B \implies B\land A$ or maybe $\forall x, y,z: [x=y \land y=z \implies x=z]$ using some simplified form of natural deduction.

Comment: Don't worry,although i am not a student, i am sure they are absolutely fine...i am just doodling around wondering to what extent proof-schemes can be mechanically applied here

Answer (score 2):

> The textbook omits all these steps and simply states :
>
> > Let $\alpha$ be an arbitrary variable assignment .There are two cases.
> >
> > First Case : $|x|_A^\alpha$ in $|Q^1|_A$.....
> >
> > Second Case : $|x|_A^\alpha$ not in $|Q^1|_A$.....
>
> There is no mention of $\beta$ anywhere or how/why these two cases are obtained.

The mechanism of variable assignment is a way to formalize the intuitive concept of "instantiation", i.e. a way to assign to a free variable of a formula $\varphi$ an object of the domain of the interpretation as its meaning.

The semantics of $∀x$ is quite simple : an universally quantified formula $∀x \ \varphi$ is true in the domain $A$ exactly if every possible "instantiation" of $\varphi$ is true in $A$.

Thus, in order to check the truth value of $∀x \ \varphi$ in $A$, we have to consider every variable assignment $\alpha$ :

> $|∀x(Q^1 x → R^2 xb)|_A = \text T \text {  iff  } |(Q^1x → R^2xb)|_A^{\alpha} = \text { T,  for every } \alpha$.

Now, the author follows a very simple "case analysis" :

either *(i)* $\alpha$ maps $x$ into one of the elements of the interpretation of predicate $Q^1$, i.e. $|Q^1|_A = \{ \text { Florence, Stockholm, Barcelona } \}$, in which case the cities are smaller than $\text {London}$, that means that $|(Q^1x)^{\alpha}|_A → |(R^2xb)^{\alpha}|_A = \text T$ (because $\text T \to \text T = \text T$),

or *(ii)* $\alpha$ maps $x$ "outside" $|Q^1|_A$, in which case the antecedent $|(Q^1x)|^{\alpha}_A$ is $\text F$.

Comment: Thank you for your response.I was just wondering whether i could use the 'proof-scheme' encountered in previous text books and apply them to this and related problems...the iff statement you have is one i had too in the OP..and i just continued,hopefully correctly, to link further iff -statements to derive a proof diagram. would you mind telling me how i should continue with my approach?

Comment: I understand WHAT the book does after it made a case distinction. I was just wondering whether one could rigourously determine WHY it made that case distinction in particular.Given that,presumably other distinctions could have been made too.?